# Real $(x,y,z)$ in fractional part and greatest integer equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculation of Real $(x,y,z)$ in

$x[x]+z\{z\}-y\{y\} = 0.16$

$y[y]+x\{x\}-z\{z\} = 0.25$

$z[z]+y\{y\}-x\{x\} = 0.49$

where $[x] = $ Greatest Integer of $x$ and $\{x\} = $ fractional part of x

$\bf{My Try}$:: Add $\bf{(i) + (ii)+(iii)}$

$x[x]+y[y]+z[z] = 0.9$

Now I did not Understand How Can I proceed after that,

Help Required

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note: I interpret $[x]$ as $[n]=n$ for all integer $n$, $[3.5]=3$, and $[-3.5]=-3$.

Claim: For all $x$, either $x[x]=0$ or $x[x]\ge 1$.
Proof: For $-1<x<1$, $x[x]=x[0]=0$.  For $x\ge 1$, $x[x]\ge x\ge 1$.  For $x\le -1$, $x[x]=(-x)[-x]\ge 1$.

Now, from the equation $x[x]+y[y]+z[z]=0.9$, we see that there are no solutions: either all three terms are zero, or at least one is $\ge 1$, in which case the sum is $\ge 1$.